# Cassandra rebalance

Tags: load-balancing, cassandra-2.0

I'm using Apache Cassandra 2.1.1 and when using nodetool status the Load for one of my nodes is about half the size of the other two while the Owns is almost equal on all the nodes.  I am somewhat new to Cassandra and don't know if I should be worried about this or not.  I have tried using repair and cleanup after restarting all the nodes, but it still appears unbalanced.  I am using GossipingPropertyFileSnitch with each node configured dc=DC1 and rack=RAC1 specified in cassandra-rackdc.properties.  I am also using Murmur3Partitioner with NetworkTopologyStrategy where my keyspace is defined as

```
CREATE KEYSPACE awl WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

I believe the problem to be with the awl keyspace since the size of the data/awl folder is the same size as reported by nodetool status.  My output for nodetool status is below.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.1.1.152  3.56 GB    256     68.4%             d42945cc-59eb-41de-9872-1fa252762797  RAC1
UN  10.1.1.153  6.8 GB     256     67.2%             065c471d-5025-4bf1-854d-52d579f2a6d3  RAC1
UN  10.1.1.154  6.31 GB    256     64.4%             46f05522-29cc-491c-ab65-334b205fc415  RAC1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect this is due to the distribution of the key values that are being inserted.  They are probably not well distributed across the possible key values, so many of them are hashing to one node.  Since you are using replication factor 2, the second replica is the next node in the ring, resulting in two nodes with more data than the third node.

You didn't show your table schema, so I don't know what you are using for the partition and clustering keys.  You want to use key values that have a high cardinality and good distribution to avoid hot spots where a lot of inserts are hashing to one node.  With a better distribution you will get better performance and more even space usage across the nodes.

Comment: That's interesting; I didn't even consider my partition key.  I'm using a Cassandra ring with VNodes with a primary key defined: PRIMARY KEY (mac,logtime).  So 

my partition key would be the mac address which determines what node that data would be stored on correct?  We currently are only storing information about 18 

different mac addresses for testing purposes.  In the future we should have thousands of MAC addresses we are storing information about.  Do you think storing 

a larger number of Mac addresses eventually lead to a more balanced cluster?

Comment: Yes, 18 is very low cardinality for the partition key given the range of all possible MAC addresses, so that is likely the cause of your data imbalance.  You may still have a problem with thousands of MAC addresses if they are for machines from one manufacturer, since they may all have similar MAC addresses rather than truly random ones.  If needed you could increase the cardinality of your partition key by using a compound partition key (i.e. pair up the MAC address with some other value like zip code or something to add more randomness to spread out the data on your nodes).